# ViewBag: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

```
ViewBag.SomeKey = "Some Value";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are missing a reference to Microsoft.CSharp. To add this reference, on your solution explorer window, right click to References, select Add Reference, go to .NET tab, find and add Microsoft.CSharp.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.

1. Solution Explorer
2. References
3. Right Click > Add Reference

[image: Add Reference to Microsoft.CSharp]